# What is the NavigationActions alternative in reactnavigation v5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to upgrade my **reactnavigation** from v4 to v5 in my React Native App.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-actions
this is not available in reactnavigation v5 documentation.

Is there any alternative for that in v5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `useNavigation` hook you're able to retrieve a reference to `navigation`, and then you can call `.navigate(...)`, etc. and navigator-dependent functions: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop

Comment: are you telling about [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) hook?

Comment: I have tried the hook in redux action function, but hook can't be used there. So how can I navigate to other route from redux action?

Comment: @KamalHossain You can have the component that calls the redux action use the hook to retrieve `navigation` and pass `navigation` when it calls the redux action.

Comment: Finally solved my problem with this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

and use `CommonActions` instead of `NavigationActions` in v5.